# Can Bokeh App on Heroku detect mobile phone and adjust its layout?

Tags: python, heroku, bokeh

I wrote a bokey app deploy on Heroku. And I try to figure out a way for app to detect screen size. I tried

```
 screen_size = pyautogui.size() 
 if screen_size[0] >= 1280:  
   layout = row(p, column(div_help, select, div_reference))
 else: 
   layout = column(p, div_help, select, div_reference) 

# Add the plot to the current document 
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

It works fine in my local, but it does not work on Heroku. 
I have no idea why? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean *"does not work"*, exactly? For that matter, what *is* the screen size on Heroku?

Comment: You need to detect screen size of users agents - i.e. browsers. `pyautogui` won't help you here, and I don't think Bokeh has anything for that as well.

Comment: I can't see the screen size of Heroku. The app on Heroku shows a blank page running my code.